# Broken breakpoints in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, python-3.6

Whenever I run my Pycharm project in Debug mode my breakpoints trigger, but only for a second. Execution then continues automatically. I get a long red stack trace in the console. I'll post my trace below but my numbers are:

- Pycharm 2021.2.2
- macOS 11.6
- Python 3.6 interpreter

2021-10-23 18:02:58.303 python3.6[32922:2949604] -[NSApplication macMinorVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff5647d1620
2021-10-23 18:02:58.314 python3.6[32922:2949604] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSApplication macMinorVersion]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff5647d1620'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2067f1db __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff203b8d92 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20701d0d -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff205e724b ***forwarding*** + 1448
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff205e6c18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011c2a4db9 SetCGColorComponents + 265
6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011c2a567a TkpGetColor + 250
7   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011c1dfaa9 Tk_GetColor + 153
8   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011c1cf8e6 Tk_Get3DBorder + 134
9   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011c1cf74f Tk_Alloc3DBorderFromObj + 127
10  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011c1e0fad DoObjConfig + 941
11  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011c1e0ae5 Tk_InitOptions + 357
12  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011c1e09c5 Tk_InitOptions + 69
13  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011c211b5c CreateFrame + 1548
14  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011c211e37 TkListCreateFrame + 151
15  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000011c2097f8 Initialize + 2168
16  _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x0000000117628adc Tkapp_New + 892
17  _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x0000000117628601 _tkinter_create + 289
18  python3.6                           0x0000000108fb4d56 _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 342
19  python3.6                           0x000000010908061a call_function + 154
20  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
21  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x0000000109d0442f __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 2431
22  python3.6                           0x0000000109071dc5 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 533
23  python3.6                           0x0000000109081394 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 420
24  python3.6                           0x0000000108f389e0 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 336
25  python3.6                           0x0000000108f5e11a method_call + 122
26  python3.6                           0x0000000108f3eede PyObject_Call + 62
27  python3.6                           0x0000000108fdba45 slot_tp_init + 117
28  python3.6                           0x0000000108fe0e0b type_call + 235
29  python3.6                           0x0000000108f38952 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 194
30  python3.6                           0x0000000109080734 call_function + 436
31  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
32  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x0000000109d0442f __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 2431
33  python3.6                           0x0000000109071dc5 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 533
34  python3.6                           0x0000000109080b06 fast_function + 374
35  python3.6                           0x00000001090806d2 call_function + 338
36  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
37  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x0000000109d0442f __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 2431
38  python3.6                           0x0000000109071dc5 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 533
39  python3.6                           0x0000000109080b06 fast_function + 374
40  python3.6                           0x00000001090806d2 call_function + 338
41  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
42  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x0000000109d0442f __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 2431
43  python3.6                           0x0000000109080a6e fast_function + 222
44  python3.6                           0x00000001090806d2 call_function + 338
45  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
46  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x0000000109d0442f __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 2431
47  python3.6                           0x0000000109080a6e fast_function + 222
48  python3.6                           0x00000001090806d2 call_function + 338
49  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
50  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x0000000109d0442f __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 2431
51  python3.6                           0x0000000109071dc5 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 533
52  python3.6                           0x0000000109080b06 fast_function + 374
53  python3.6                           0x00000001090806d2 call_function + 338
54  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
55  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x0000000109d0442f __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 2431
56  python3.6                           0x0000000109080a6e fast_function + 222
57  python3.6                           0x00000001090806d2 call_function + 338
58  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
59  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x0000000109d0442f __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 2431
60  python3.6                           0x0000000109080a6e fast_function + 222
61  python3.6                           0x00000001090806d2 call_function + 338
62  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
63  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x0000000109d0442f __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 2431
64  python3.6                           0x0000000109071dc5 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 533
65  python3.6                           0x0000000109081394 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 420
66  python3.6                           0x0000000108f389e0 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 336
67  python3.6                           0x0000000108f5e11a method_call + 122
68  pydevd_cython_darwin_36_64.cpython- 0x0000000109c27411 __Pyx_PyObject_Call + 97
69  pydevd_cython_darwin_36_64.cpython- 0x0000000109c4b7b5 __pyx_pw_14_pydevd_bundle_26pydevd_cython_darwin_36_64_9PyDBFrame_5do_wait_suspend + 165
70  python3.6                           0x0000000108fb475e PyCFunction_Call + 142
71  pydevd_cython_darwin_36_64.cpython- 0x0000000109c27411 __Pyx_PyObject_Call + 97
72  pydevd_cython_darwin_36_64.cpython- 0x0000000109c311cf __pyx_f_14_pydevd_bundle_26pydevd_cython_darwin_36_64_9PyDBFrame_trace_dispatch + 33135
73  pydevd_cython_darwin_36_64.cpython- 0x0000000109c728e7 **pyx_pf_14_pydevd_bundle_26pydevd_cython_darwin_36_64_12ThreadTracer_2__call** + 18791
74  python3.6                           0x0000000108f38952 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 194
75  python3.6                           0x00000001090e5f55 trace_trampoline + 133
76  python3.6                           0x000000010907a8ff _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 29919
77  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x0000000109d052ec __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 6204
78  python3.6                           0x0000000109071dc5 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 533
79  python3.6                           0x000000010906cd35 builtin_exec + 341
80  python3.6                           0x0000000108fb4d56 _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 342
81  python3.6                           0x000000010908061a call_function + 154
82  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
83  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x0000000109d052ec __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 6204
84  python3.6                           0x0000000109071dc5 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 533
85  python3.6                           0x0000000109080b06 fast_function + 374
86  python3.6                           0x00000001090806d2 call_function + 338
87  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
88  pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64 0x0000000109d052ec __pyx_f_18_pydevd_frame_eval_35pydevd_frame_evaluator_darwin_36_64_get_bytecode_while_frame_eval + 6204
89  python3.6                           0x0000000109080a6e fast_function + 222
90  python3.6                           0x00000001090806d2 call_function + 338
91  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
92  python3.6                           0x0000000109071dc5 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 533
93  python3.6                           0x0000000109080b06 fast_function + 374
94  python3.6                           0x00000001090806d2 call_function + 338
95  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
96  python3.6                           0x0000000109080a6e fast_function + 222
97  python3.6                           0x00000001090806d2 call_function + 338
98  python3.6                           0x0000000109078c3e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 22558
99  python3.6                           0x0000000109071dc5 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 533
100 python3.6                           0x00000001090d52db PyRun_FileExFlags + 235
101 python3.6                           0x00000001090d4ca8 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 504
102 python3.6                           0x00000001090fa2ca run_file + 170
103 python3.6                           0x00000001090f9492 Py_Main + 2930
104 python3.6                           0x0000000108f31a04 main + 276
105 libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20528f3d start + 1
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be caused by some lack of Mac support from matplotlib.

Using:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as pet
```

as suggested by "krisdigital" [here](https://github.com/MTG/sms-tools/issues/36) seems to fix my problem.